# Odata Dynamics CRM 365 from contact to account

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, odata

How can i use Odata with Expand property to fetch a custom property on account while I am on the contact entity?

I was trying this:
`api/data/v9.0/contacts?$select=id,name,address1_city,address1_line1&$expand=parentcustomerid_account($select=custom_prop)&$filter=_parentcustomerid_value eq '{accountId}'`

but this aint working. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `parentcustomerid_value` to the select. Not sure what I missed in the beginning